# javascript animate div 100px left then 100px right?

Tags: javascript

can someone please help i am trying to animate a div so that it moves 100px to the left and then returns back to its original position/so moves back over to the right by 100px.

i want it to do this 5 times before stoping the animation.

can someone please show me how to get this to work thanks.

```
<script>

function loop() {
    $('.sign_up').animate({right:'+=100px'}, 1000, function() {
        $(this).animate({left:'-=100px'}, 1000, function() {
            loop();
        });
    });
}

$(function() {
    loop();
});

</script>
```

Comment: call the function 5 times

Answer (score 0):

You can use a counter to determine when to stop looping. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var loopCount = 0;
function loop() {
    $('.sign_up').animate({ left: '-=100px' }, 1000, function () {
        $(this).animate({ left: '+=100px' }, 1000, function () {
            loopCount++;
            if (loopCount < 5)
                loop();
        });
    });
}

$(function () {
    loop();
});
</script>
```

I also switched the first `animate` statement to animate to the left using the `left` css property instead of `right`. This code worked for for me when I declared the `sign_up` `div` as follows:

```
<div class="sign_up"  style="position:absolute;top:300px;left:300px;width:200px;height:200px;background:Green;">
    Hello!
</div>
```

**UPDATE**
Here's a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/peFVT/